# R installation errors on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, failed-installation

I am trying to install R on my ubuntu 14.04 and i am incurring lot of errors in this aspect

when i run r-base-core i am getting following errors , please let me know what changes i have to do to install these broken packages

```
dev@dev-OptiPlex-780:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.23) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 is to be installed
               Depends: libgomp1 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have checked the installation version of Libc6 and this is what i obtained

```
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-0ubuntu6.9
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.9
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-0ubuntu6.9 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.19-0ubuntu6 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libc6-dev:
  Installed: 2.19-0ubuntu6.9
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.9
```

and even libgomp1

```
 Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
  Candidate: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3
  Version table:
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Also  r-base-core cache

```
root@dev-OptiPlex-780:/home/dev# apt-cache policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.3.1-1xenial0
  Version table:
     3.3.1-1xenial0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ xenial/ Packages
     3.3.1-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/marutter/rrutter/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     3.3.0-2xenial0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ xenial/ Packages
     3.3.0-2trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.3.0-1xenial0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ xenial/ Packages
     3.3.0-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.5-1xenial 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ xenial/ Packages
     3.2.5-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.4-revised-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.4-1trusty 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.3-6trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.3-4trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.3-3trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.3-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.2-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.1-4trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.1-3trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.1-2trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.1-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.0-4trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.2.0-1trusty 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.1.3-1trusty 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.1.2-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.1.1-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.1.0-1trusty0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ trusty/ Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I suspected [in my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467494/r-installation-errors-on-ubuntu-14-04#comment66258284_39467494), you have 'confused' your system by pointing to Ubuntu 16.04 aka xenial as shown in your output:

```
root@dev-OptiPlex-780:/home/dev# apt-cache policy r-base-core
r-base-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.3.1-1xenial0
  Version table:
     3.3.1-1xenial0 0
        500 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/ xenial/ Packages
```

The fix is simple. In `/etc/apt/sources.list` or one of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` replace `xenial` with `trusty` and run `apt-get update`.  After that you should be able to update.

Comment: I do not see sources.list in /etc  folder

Comment: I dropped an (important) `apt/` in those paths. Now corrected.

Comment: when i change from xenial to trusty and save the file , its not allowing me to save

Comment: Edit via `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cran.list` (or whatever your filename)